# htaccess friendly URL rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have recently change my hosting and i need a htaccess rewrite rule for my files. I tried many examples but no one really works for my case. I have never been really good in htaccess and on my older hosting i didn't really need anything it just worked but here is not. Basically i want that my PHP files are without extensions and treated like a directory. So for example i have a URLs like these:

> www.domain.com/file1/{id}/{nick}

So for example:

> www.domain.com/myfile1/104/username
>
> www.domain.com/myotherfile/455/nick

File1 in this case is a PHP file and {id} and {nick} are changable. I have this structure on my entire site for many other PHP files etc. So if possible i want **one universal rule for all files**. I tried with htaccess to remove php extenstion etc but all I got is 404 error. Also URL in browser should stay friendly without PHP extension. So in my case if i rewrite my URL manually in:
www.domain.com/file1.php/{id}/{nick} it worked but i don't want to change all the links etc on my website. So all i want is to hide PHP extension and treat PHP files as directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this single and generic front controller rule in site root .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but i got this: No input file specified. When i tried to visit an url such as: www.domain.com/file/123/user

Comment: This rule is working fine on my Apache. Test it with just this rule in your site root .htaccess

Comment: I have only this in my htaccess on root and doesnt work. It's strange but i am looking for a solution for a few hours now and nothing work.

Comment: If `www.domain.com/file.php/123/user` works and `www.domain.com/file/123/user` gives `No input file specified` then it doesn't appear to be rewrite problem but some other code/config issue.

Comment: Tried your solution again and modify it a little and looks like it works now. I changed the last line from yours to: RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1.php/$2 [L] and it WORKS now. Thanks!

Comment: Well it works but .php is added to URL. Didn't notice before. Will try to find a solution for this. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Updated code doesnt work either. I contacted hosting provider and they are also not sure about what to do. I found a Multiview option "Options +Multiviews" which according to description could work in my case and i tried it and dont work either. So i am not sure what to do for now

Comment: Only your server admins can help because this is tested and working rule on my Apache. So most likely it is some local config/setup issue.